# Transactions with different isolation levels for Ignite's SQL layer

Tags: sql, transactions, ignite, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Apache Ignite's documentation specifically mentions that weak isolation levels and ACID compliant transactions are only offered for cache operations but not for the SQL API. However, it is also mentioned that the functionality *will be* added in version 2.1. 
I could not find anything in the most recent documentation (V2.5.0) regarding this feature.

Can anyone please tell me if it has been added and maybe refer to some examples?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is under active development. You should see a release by the end of August.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dmitriy!